# Knockoutjs datatable with paging and checkbox check all databinding fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatables

My check all for checkbox binding works perfectly fine with jquery datatable without paging but once I enable paging and tick select all and click next page or any page number, check boxes belong to that page were not checked but my observableArry for selected Items were updated. Hope you can help me guys. I already spent hours or this one and cant figure out what really happen.

here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jfmjason/d8mutbL4/2/

**here is my html**

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value:true, checked: $root.selectAll"/> Select All
    <br />
     Selected People : <span data-bind="text:$root.selectedPeople().length"></span>
<br />
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="example" style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: people, dataTableOptions: {
                          jQueryUI: true,
                          scrollY: 250,
                          paging: true,
                          dom: 'rtip',
                          columns:[
                              {width: '30px'},
                              {width: '30px'},
                              {width: '100px'},
                              {width: '100px'}
                          ]
                      }
                  }">
            <tr style="height:50px;">
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value:$data, checked: $root.selectedPeople"/>
                </td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: id" /> </td>
                 <td> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                <td> <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>

    </div>
```

**And the Script**

***ForeachBindingHandler***

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
        page: 0,
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
          ko.unwrap(options.data);
          if(options.dataTableOptions.paging){
            valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
                var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
                ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
                table.destroy();
            }, null, 'arrayChange');          
          }
            var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
                if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);  
                }
            });
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {        
            var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
            ko.unwrap(options.data);
            var table;
            if(!options.dataTableOptions.paging){
              table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
                table.destroy();
            }
            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
            table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
            if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
               if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0) 
                   table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
               else 
                   table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
            }        
            if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```

***Model And Binding Initialization***

```
// Person ViewModel
     var Person = function (data, parent) {
         var that = this;
         this.id = data.id;
         this.isEdit = ko.observable(false);
         this.first = ko.observable(data.first);
         this.last = ko.observable(data.last);
         this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
         this.editButtonText = ko.computed(function () {
             return that.isEdit() ? 'Save' : 'Edit';
         });
         this.full = ko.computed(function () {
             return this.first() + " " + this.last();
         }, this);
         // Subscribe a listener to the observable properties for the table
         // and invalidate the DataTables row when they change so it will redraw


     };
     //Main ViewModel
     var ViewModel = new function () {
             var that = this;
             this.selectAll = ko.observable();
             this.selectAll.subscribe(function(value){

             if(value){
             ko.utils.arrayPushAll(that.selectedPeople, that.people());
             }else{that.selectedPeople([]);}
             })
             this.selectedPeople = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
             this.people = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
         };

    $(document).ready(function () {

         // Convert the data set into observable objects, and will also add the
         // initial data to the table
         ko.mapping.fromJS(
         data, {
             key: function (data) {
                 return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
             },
             create: function (options) {
                 return new Person(options.data, ViewModel);
             }
         },
         ViewModel.people);

     ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
 });
```

***Initial Dataset***

```
// Initial data set
 var data = [{
     id: 1,
     first: "Allan",
     last: "Jardine",
     age: 86
 }, {
     id: 2,
     first: "Bob",
     last: "Smith",
     age: 54
 }, {
     id: 3,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }, {
     id: 4,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 5,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }, {
     id:6,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 7,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 8,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 9,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 10,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 11,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }, {
     id: 12,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }
 , {
     id: 13,
     first: "Jimmy",
     last: "Jones",
     age: 32
 }];
```

Comment: Just mentioning "it fails" and adding *that* much code to your question isn't very helpful to others trying to help you. Try to trim your code down to a more [mcve], be specific about why/how "it fails" and add info you gathered during debugging and trying to fix it yourself, please.

Comment: thank you for your comment @Jeroe I already updated my post

Comment: What behaviour are you looking for? It looks like clicking the select all does select everything, and of course when you click next, datatables refreshes everything so it is not clicked.  Do you want select all to select only the visible items? Or recheck all when next is pressed? or something else?

Comment: yes @brianlmerritt i want to checked all the checkboxes including the hidden checkboxes

Comment: So put the checked property in to the data set and make it observable, per record? I think you need to create a working model and we can then help you easily and you can help yourself too.